# Passing filter options to angularjs directive

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to create a directive that can take most any json object and can generate select options or create a ul li dropdown based on if users are on mobile devices or desktops and the attributes on my html tag.

plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/2GFVhx0DgEsa0dfv9l5C

In my index page I have a div that I have added attributes to give the designer the flexibility to specifiy what **data** (json object to use), **opt-value** (the value to be used from the object), **opt-description** (the text to be show in a select or ul li) and **opt-filter** (what i would like to pass to the directive to handle for formatting of the dates or other filters in the opt-description in this case I know it's a date.)

Index page:

```
<div generic-dropdown click-callback="callbackdateselectionchanged(value)" data="invoiceItems" opt-value="invoiceNumber" opt-description="invoiceDate"  opt-filter=" |date:'MM/dd/yyyy'" selected-item="selectedChoice"></div>
```

In my controller I have a object $scope.invoiceItems that is a list of invoices.

Controller:

```
$scope.invoiceItems = [{"invoiceNumber":"3067095","displayInvoiceNumber":"260996530","invoiceDate":"2013-08-01T05:00:00.0000000","invoiceAmount":0,"balanceDue":0,"dueDate":"2013-08-31T05:00:00.0000000","hasSubAccount":false},{"invoiceNumber":"3086446","displayInvoiceNumber":"260374907","invoiceDate":"2013-07-01T05:00:00.0000000","invoiceAmount":0,"balanceDue":0,"dueDate":"2013-07-31T05:00:00.0000000","hasSubAccount":false},{"invoiceNumber":"3053215","displayInvoiceNumber":"255453017","invoiceDate":"2012-12-01T06:00:00.0000000","invoiceAmount":0,"balanceDue":0,"dueDate":"2012-12-31T06:00:00.0000000","hasSubAccount":false}];
```

Directive:

```
app.directive('genericDropdown', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
        data: '=',
        clickCallback: '&',
        selectedItem: '=',
    },
    templateUrl: 'genericdropdown.html',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.optValue = attrs.optValue;
        scope.optDescription = attrs.optDescription;
        scope.optFilter = attrs.optFilter;
    }
};
```

});

Template used by the Directive which works if I put the filter on the ng-options.

```
<select ng-model="ngModel" ng-options="a[optValue] as a[optDescription] | date:'MM/dd/yyyy' for a in data "  ng-change="clickCallback({value: ngModel})">
  <option selected>Select an Item</option>
</select>
```

What I would like to see is if I can pass the filter in as a param and use it like this, however trying a few times it will return empty items. I guess the question is, is there a way to pass a string into the ng-options that can be used to filter the data in the select?

```
ng-options="a[optValue] as a[optDescription] optFilter for a in data"
```

Comment: look into using `template:function(elem,attrs){ /* return template string*/}`.....lets you concatenate whatever you need into the template from attributes or angular elemnt so you could create the filter on the fly from attributes. May not be best solution for your case, but far more flexible than trying to get everything into fixed markup

Comment: charlietfl: thanks, this works! I had to update the version of angularjs to at least 1.1.4 (had been using the current 1.0.8 stable version) to get it to use the template: to return the function. I've updated the plunker.